# What is -c and nrow doing in this function?

Tags: r

What is the purpose of `-c` and `nrow` in this function?

```
bdf <- by(bdf, bdf$Serial_number, function(SN, k) {
                     SN[-c(1:k, (nrow(SN)-k+1):nrow(SN)),]
                     }, k = 10)
```

`by()` splits the data frame bdf by the second argument Serial_number and `apply`s the function function(SN, k) in the third argument. I don't understand the body of the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`c()` creates a vector. `-` makes the numbers in the vector negative. The vector is in the "row" position of `[`, so it is omitting the rows from 1 to `k`, and from `nrow(SN) - k + 1` to the end of the data frame. So it's chopping off the first `k` and last `k - 1` rows of the data frame.

Comment: I've a question again: When the 2k rows are omitted, why shall the numbers be made negative by -c?

Comment: You seem to have things backwards. The numbers are made negative so that the rows are omitted. That's what negative indices do. `letters[1]` gives you the first letter, `letters[-1]` omits the first letter. `letters[c(1, 3, 5)]` gives the first, third, and fifth letters; `letters[-c(1, 3, 5)]` is the same as `letters[c(-1, -3, -5)]` and it omits the first, third and fifth letters.

Comment: For more details, I'd recommend reading through some [R resources](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info), *An Introduction to R* is quite good.

Comment: Thank you! I even bought me a book but it's still difficult to enter a specific level to teach oneself. I also had this by going from C to C++..  it was something complete different and now it feels the same..    but anyhow, thanks again! :)